# SQLite WP8.1 C# error

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I tried to work with SQLite with my project, and I found this tutrial and it close to the project idea.
[Windows Phone 8.1 SQLite: How to Store Data in Database](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/55275a/windows-phone-8-1-sqlite-how-to-store-data-in-database/)

the code is very simple, I just modify it with my table **WritePadFileContent**

```
public WritePadFileContent ReadWritePadFileContent(int writePadFileContentid)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existingWritePadFileContent = dbConn.Query<WritePadFileContent>("select * from WritePadFileContents where Id =" + writePadFileContentid).FirstOrDefault();
            return existingWritePadFileContent;
        }
    }
```

The problem is started with

```
dbConn.Query<WritePadFileContent>("select * from WritePadFileContents where Id =" + writePadFileContentid).FirstOrDefault();
```

and the error is

> Error 4   'WritePad_CSharpSample.Model.WritePadFileContent' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Query(string, params object[])' C:\Users\juste 3al faza\Contacts\Documents\WritePad SDK\WritePad_CSharpMetroSample\WritePad_CSharpSample.WindowsPhone\Helpers\DatabaseHelperClass.cs    54  51  WritePad_CSharpSample.WindowsPhone

**Solved**
,just add public to the class, and add a default constructor with 0 parameters

Comment: Post you solution as an answer and accept it, if it solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What he needed to do was add a default constructor to the class. He simply added the code below into his existing class.

```
public WritePadFileContent() { }
```